# Having difficulty plotting linear system of equations

Tags: plotting, graphics, function-construction, graphics3d, linear-algebra

I have a function `eqsfromMatrix[..]` that generates linear equations from a matrix which I would like to plot but there seems to be no direct way to plot them. I think I should probably solve for one of the variables before attempting to plot them but do not know how to manipulate them. I've tried everything from `Plot[...]` to `Graphics[...]` but they rendered very poorly. One would think there would be a straightforward or direct way to plot 3 linear equations but it eludes me for now. My goal is to plot the lines formed from matrix and show where they intersect if there is a solution. Below in the code I have 3 matrices of 2, 3, 4 dimensions which I would like to plot if at all possible.

```
eqsfromMatrix[mat_, b_ : None, piv_ : "x"] := 
 Block[{len, abc, pivot, diff, vars, scals, eqs},
  len = Length[mat];
  abc = Alphabet[];
  pivot = Flatten[Position[abc, piv]][[1]]; 
  start[m_] := pivot /; len <= 26 - pivot + 1;
  start[m_] := 26 - len + 1;
  end[m_] = start[m] + len - 1;
  vars = Take[abc, {start[m], end[m]}];
  eqs = mat.vars;
  scals = 
   Switch[b, None, Return[eqs], _List, b, 1, Take[abc, {1, len}], 0, 
    Table[0, len]];
  Table[eqs[[i]] == scals[[i]], {i, 1, len}]
  ]
(*m={{1,0,1,3},{-1,3,2,1},{3,2,4,5},{8,3,5,3}};
b={-1,3,2,4};*)
(*m={{1,0,1},{-1,3,1},{3,4,5}};
b={3,2,4};*)
m = {{1, 2}, {3, 2}};
b = {1, -2};
sol = LinearSolve[m, b]
eqs = eqsfromMatrix[m, b]
eqs[[1]] // Expand
Solve[eqs[[1]], y]

Plot[eqsfromMatrix[m, b], {x, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: You mean `ContourPlot` and `ContourPlot3D`? I don't think there's an easy way for 4D, though. BTW your code can be simplified to `ContourPlot[Thread[m.{x, y} == b] // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For 2 or 3 dimensions:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqnsFromMatrix[m_?MatrixQ, b_?VectorQ] := Block[
  {x, n = Length@m, var, eqns, pt = LinearSolve[m, b], min, max, plt, 
   grph},
  min = Floor@Min@pt;
  max = Ceiling@Max@pt;
  var = Array[x, n];
  eqns = Thread[m.var == b];
  plt = If[n == 2, ContourPlot, ContourPlot3D];
  grph = If[n == 2, Graphics, Graphics3D];
  Column[{
    Column@(eqns /. x[k_] :> Subscript[x, k]),
    Show[
     plt[Evaluate@eqns, 
      Evaluate[Sequence @@ Thread[{var, min, max}]],
      ImageSize -> Medium],
     grph[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[8],
       Tooltip[Point[pt], pt]}]]}]]

eqnsFromMatrix[{{1, 2}, {3, 2}}, {1, -2}]
```

[image]

```
eqnsFromMatrix[{{1, 0, 1}, {-1, 3, 1}, {3, 4, 5}}, {3, 2, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. i had been struggling with this all day.